# Running into errors while executing circle program in java

Tags: java, printf, degrees, radians

I am having trouble inputting the radius of a circle and angle of a circle (deg) while receiving the output with the values given plus the angle in radians, arc length and polar area all as floats. Here is what I have.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyCircles {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("1st: Please enter a radius (integer) :");
        int radius01 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("1st: Please enter angle (in degrees between 0 and 360) :");
        int angledeg01 = input.nextInt();
        input.close();

        System.out.printf("%s%14s%15s%19s%24s\n", "Radius (inch)", "Angle (deg)", "Angle (rad)", "ArcLength (inch)", "Polar Area (sq. inch)");
        System.out.printf("%13d%14d", radius01, angledeg01);
        float anglerad01 = radius01 * (Math.PI / 180.0f);
```

Trying to achieve this:

```
Radius(inch)  Angle(deg)  Angle(rad)  ArcLength(inch)  Polar Area(sq.inch) 
            3          31        0.54            1.62                 2.43
```

All in columns but I keep running into cannot convert into float error. Also cannot use the MathtoRadians functions. Must use hard code to show work. Suggestions?

Comment: What input are you giving it and what is it printing on that input?

Comment: Also note that [Math.PI](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#PI) is a double, not a float.

Answer (score 0):

anglerad01  should be double instead of float

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("1st: Please enter a radius (integer) :");
        int radius01 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("1st: Please enter angle (in degrees between 0 and 360) :");
        int angledeg01 = input.nextInt();
        input.close();

        System.out.printf("%s%14s%15s%19s%24s\n", "Radius (inch)", "Angle (deg)", "Angle (rad)", "ArcLength (inch)", "Polar Area (sq. inch)");
        System.out.printf("%13d%14d", radius01, angledeg01);
       double anglerad01 = radius01 * (Math.PI / 180.0f);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is convert Math.PI to a float since it is a `double` and not a `float`:

```
    float anglerad01 = (radius01 * ((float)Math.PI / 180.0f));
```

The reason we need to do this conversion is because, while both `floats` and `doubles` are data types that represent decimals, they are not the same data type since `doubles` are more precise.

`Math.PI` gives you a constant in the form of a `double`, and so without casting to a `float`, you divide the `double` by a `double`, giving you a `double`, and then multiply it by an `int` to get a `double`. This leads you to be giving a `float` variable the value of a `double`.

However, once you cast `Math.PI` to a `float`, your final value will also be a `float`, making the variable legal.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained why.

Answer (score 0):

First I read it wrong, I made the suggestion on the bases that `Math.toRadians` you are not able to use in your program due to some error.

So now its for what you have asked I hope.

1.data type double for `anglerad01`

2.As the expression will result a double its obvious as here we used `Math.Pi`.

3.float data type cannot take value of double data type.

4.So double `anglerad01` should be used.

Also, for **Radians = (Degrees × π)/180°** . Degree is used to calculate radian not radius of circle.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("1st: Please enter a radius (integer) :");
    int radius01 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("1st: Please enter angle (in degrees between 0 and 360) :");
    int angledeg01 = input.nextInt();
    input.close();
    double anglerad01 = radius01 * (Math.PI / 180.0f);


    System.out.printf("%s%14s%15s%19s%24s\n", "Radius (inch)", "Angle (deg)", "Angle (rad)", "ArcLength (inch)", "Polar Area (sq. inch)");
    System.out.printf("%13d%14d%18f", radius01, angledeg01, anglerad01 );
}
```